# Is the rows of matrix $\{\{1,2,2\}, \{−1,2,1\}, \{0,8,6\}\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is the rows of matrix  $\{\{1,2,2\}, \{−1,2,1\}, \{0,8,6\}\}$ a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

The answer given to me for this is "no, it is not".

But can anyone tell me why? I solved it through row reduction but I don't understand why it is not a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the $3$ vectors from your matrix are $(1,2,2)$, $(-1,2,1)$ and $(0,8,6)$. If so, they are not linearly independent, since $2$ times the first plus $2$ times the second gives the third one. In particular,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
2 \times (1,2,2) + 2 \times (-1,2,1) & = (2,4,4) + (-2,4,2) \\
& = (0,8,6)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, they cannot cannot be a basis for $R^3$ as that requires $3$ linearly independent vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
octave:1> rref([1, 2,2; -1, 2, 1; 0, 8, 6])
ans =

   1.00000   0.00000   0.50000
   0.00000   1.00000   0.75000
   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
```

Since you mention row reduction, I have included the RREF. Row reduction doesn't change the dimension. As you can see, there are only two linearly independent rows but the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $3$. Hence it can't be a basis.